# Why does Perl's Crypt::SSLeay timeout on Intel Mac OS X machines?

Tags: perl, ssl, https, timeout

A have a Perl cron job that recently started having its HTTPS connections start failing with an error of "500 SSL read timeout".  I've tracked that the error is being thrown as part of an alarm in [Crypt::SSLeay](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Crypt-SSLeay), but I don't know if this is simply something taking too long to respond.

So far, I've adjusted the timeout from the default 30 seconds to 10 minutes and it still times out.  I've moved the script to other machines, and those on Intel Mac OS X systems all time out, while those under Linux, or on PPC Mac OS X systems run fine, so I don't think it's changes on the network or remote server.

When the process started having problems does not coincide with any software updates or reboots on the machine, and I've contacted the server I'm connecting to, and everyone claims that they haven't changed anything.

Does anyone have recommendations on trying to debug HTTPS, or have you ever seen this behavior and give recommendations on something I might've overlooked at that could've caused this problem?

Comment: What about the versions of your Perl Modules (and Perl itself come to that)? Are they all the same across the machines?

Comment: Does the connection succeed with a browser? Can you sniff the packets using Wireshark? You can also get a decent picture of what is going with openssl s_client, though you may have to configure it's trusted certificates.

Comment: @Maxwell Troy Milton King : The modules are all the same, but I've got different versions of perl on all of the machines (default perl 5.8.x on the OS, but the intel machines are running 10.5 and 10.6, while the ppc are running 10.4 and 10.5)

Comment: @GregS : I can't easily check with a browser (it's a POST ... I might be able to make an HTML form to fake it, but I won't be back in the office 'til Tuesday) when I tried a GET from one of the machines that worked, I got an error about certificates (sorry, it's been a week since I've been in front of the machines, due to the DC snow).  curl sits forever on a GET, and if I use '-F' to pass the authentication,  I get `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`, with a 248 byte response (but -D doesn't work for HTTPS) ... time to try s_client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be specific to OS X and related directly to OpenSSL, so not unique to perl. It possibly has to do with one of the latest security updates from Apple (2010-001).

I'm having the same issue with:

- python httplib (uploads over ~64k produce 'The read operation timed out' error). Smaller uploads over SSL work. Uploads of all sizes over HTTP work.
- curl over HTTPS. curl times out. Same curl command from Linux works fine with both HTTP and HTTPS. curl on OS X over HTTP also works fine.

I found a few places online that cover similar issues across different programming languages / software. I can only post one...
https://blog.torproject.org/blog/apple-broke-openssl-which-breaks-tor-os-x

Comment: Strange ... I hadn't thought it coincided w/ an update, but upon further checking, it seems I didn't ask all of the sysadmins -- and in checking /Library/Receipts/InstallHistory.plist, I see "Security Update 2010-001" was installed 15 min before the problem showed up.  (and I'm guessing, didn't require a reboot)

Comment: I just did a quick check on Tiger (which was offline for a while, so certainly didn't have the update) and it all worked well.

Oddly though, I would have expected a different version of OpenSSL, but both Tiger and Leopard are showing the same version 0.9.7l...

Comment: another note and a potential workaround/solution - the timeout seems to take place when uploading/sending small chunk sizes. Increasing the buffer/chunk size (to about 8192 bytes) for each send seemed to allow an upload to go through. Only tested on python, so can't comment on perl, but might be worth a try.